# Combining The Results Of Two Linq Queries Into A Single Var?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two different databases that contain two tables with the exact same design.  How do I combine the results from these two queries most efficiently?  I know I can put the results of each into a dictionary or array or whatever, but I would like to think that there is a simpler way to do this.

```
var db1 = //A database object connected to database1
var db2 = //A database object connected to database2

var result1 = db1.table.where(a=>a.value>0);
var result2 = db2.table.where(a=>a.value>0);

var resultSum = result1+result2; //???
```

Thanks!

Addendum: Concat or Union, which is better for this particular case and why?  Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can only combine enumerations of the same type, you could project both to a common class and then concatenate them:

```
var result1 = db1.table.Where(a=>a.value>0).Select( x=> new Foo() { /*set props*/ });
var result2 = db2.table.Where(a=>a.value>0).Select( x=> new Foo() { /*set props*/ });

var resultSum = result1.Concat(result2);
```

Comment: `Union` would remove duplicates, doesn't seem to apply in your case

Answer (score 10):

```
var resultUnion = Enumerable.Union(result1, result2)
```

or, using the externsion method syntax,

```
var resultUnion = result1.Union(result2);
```

Comment: how about var resultUnion = Enumerable.Union(db1.table.where(blah),db2.table.where(blah))? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is with Concat:

```
var resultingEnumerable = result1.Concat(result2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx) and [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) operators.

Comment: Union or Concat, which is better?

Comment: I would expect the only difference being that Concat doesn't remove distinct values (duplicates) - therefore probably resulting in a Union All in SQL terms.