# how to combine two linq query into one in c#

Tags: c#, linq

```
var patientList = uow.patientRepo.Get(p=>p.NutrititnistId == nutritionistId).select(y=>y.Id).toList();


var logList = uow.changeLogRepo.Get(c=>(c.EntityType.Equals("Program")) ||(patientList.any(s=>s==c.PatientId)));
```

Instead of retrieving that patientList, I want to combine that two linq statements into one statement
what can I do..?

Comment: you can definitely find examples of  this on line with a simple google search here is a previously asked question on `SO` look up how to use the `Concat` function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235858/combining-the-results-of-two-linq-queries-into-a-single-var

Comment: You have it correct as is. Why do you want to change?

Comment: first i have to load patientList and then i will match the patientId in list , but  it takes more time to load that lists,that's why i want to combine the both

Comment: What types do the collections contain? You're querying two different collections, potentially containing two different types and in one case doing a projection on the results while you don't in the other. Because of that it's not really possible to just simply 'combine' the queries. You could join the results and compose everything into one line of code (probably what you're looking for) perhaps but you can't just combine two queries that execute against different sources, it is simply impossible. Give the types and some idea what the results should be and I'll work on a solution.

Comment: var patientList = uow.PatientRepo.GetByNutritionist(nutritionistId).Select(p => p.Id).ToList();

              var LogList = uow.ChangeLogRepo.Get(c => (c.EntityType.Equals("Program")) || ((patientList.Any(s=>s==c.PatientId))),q => q.OrderByDescending(c => c.DateTime), "", (count - 1) * itemsPerPage, itemsPerPage).ToList();
These are 2 linq queries i want to combine

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an association between ChangeLog and Patient, you should be able to do this...

```
var logList = uow.changeLogRepo.Get(c=>(c.EntityType.Equals("Program")) ||
    (c => c.Patients.any(p => p.NutrititnistId == nutritionistId)));
```

Comment: changeLog contains PatientId, & I want to compare that patientId with PatientList.
var patientList = uow.patientRepo.Get(p=>p.NutrititnistId == nutritionistId).select(y=>y.Id).toList();     what should i do..??

Comment: Are you saying the table changeLog has PatientId?  If so, does the ENTITY have a Patient class?  If so, then what I've provided should work as a single query.

Comment: var patientList = uow.PatientRepo.GetByNutritionist(nutritionistId).Select(p => p.Id).ToList();

              var LogList = uow.ChangeLogRepo.Get(c => (c.EntityType.Equals("Program")) || ((patientList.Any(s=>s==c.PatientId))),q => q.OrderByDescending(c => c.DateTime), "", (count - 1) * itemsPerPage, itemsPerPage).ToList();
These are 2 linq queries i want to combine