# Is the're a way to join multiple linq queries in to get results based on user selection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, linq, repository

I have a windows form that selects results based on user selection : the result is shown in datagridview based on user choice. Let me explain more, if the user selected an account number the result shows the data of this specific account. Same thing for suppliers and date.

To do so, I'm using four linq methods to query my database on each user choice :

PS : RepositoryLINQ is my LINQ class (LINQ (Language Integrated Query) is uniform query syntax in C# and VB.NET used to save and retrieve data from different sources. It is integrated in C# or VB, thereby eliminating the mismatch between programming languages and databases, as well as providing a single querying interface for different types of data sources.)

I write all my database queries in this part so I can have some layered app.

```
public IList<RepositoryLINQ> 
GetAllJoinCmp(DateTime _from, DateTime _To)
{
   try
   {
      var _tbl = from tbl in _db.mytable
      join tblc in _db.joinedtable on tbl.ID equals 
      tblc.ID
      where tbl.Date >= _from 
      && _To >= tbl.Date
      orderby tbl.Date
      select new RepositoryLINQ
      {
         //some attributes
      };

      return _tbl.ToList();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      _ErrMsg = ex.Message;
      return null;
   }
}

public IList<RepositoryLINQ> 
GetAllJoinCmpByCmp(DateTime _from, DateTime _To)
{
   try
   {
      var _tbl = from tbl in _db.mytable
      join tblc in _db.joinedtable on tbl.ID equals 
      tblc.ID
      where tbl.Date >= _from
      && _To >= tbl.Date
      && tblc.accountID.Equals(this._accountID)
      orderby tbl.Date
      select new RepositoryLINQ
      {
         //some attributes
      };
      return _tbl.ToList();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      _ErrMsg = ex.Message;
      return null;
   }
}

public IList<RepositoryLINQ> 
GetAllJoinCmpBySupp(DateTime _from, DateTime _To)
{
   try
   {
      var _tbl = from tbl in _db.table
      join tblc in _db.joinedtable on tbl.ID equals 
      tblc.ID
      where tbl.Date >= _from
      && _To >= tbl.Date 
      && tbl.SupplierID.Equals(this._SupplierID)
      orderby tbl.Date 
      select new RepositoryLINQ
      {
         //some attributes
      };
      return _tbl.ToList();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      _ErrMsg = ex.Message;
      return null;
   }
}

public IList<RepositoryLINQ> 
GetAllJoinCmpByCmpBySupp(DateTime _from, DateTime _To)
{
   try
   {
      var _tbl = var _tbl = from tbl in _db.mytable
      join tblc in _db.joinedtable on tbl.ID equals 
      tblc.ID
      where tbl.Date >= _from
      && _To >= tbl.Date
      && tblc.accountID.Equals(this._accountID)
      && tbl.SupplierID.Equals(this._SupplierID)
      orderby tbl.mytable
      select new RepositoryLINQ
      {
         //some attributes
      };
      return _tbl.ToList();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      _ErrMsg = ex.Message;
      return null;
   }
}
```

With this method, my code is a bit complex and slow. 
My question is : how can I join these queries?
I can maybe use left/right join propreties. It seems not complicated but I couldn't figure it how.

Comment: May be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235858/combining-the-results-of-two-linq-queries-into-a-single-var

Comment: thank you I'll try this out and I'll leave a feedback.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by combining to a single query? Someone may think combining is Union, someone may think it's Concat, someone may think it's left-joining all the queries. Do all these queries have the same properties? What are `RepositoryLINQ` properties? What's bad with these 4 methods and what's your goal by combining them to a single one? What's the expected result? It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I edited my question so it can be more clear what I need.

Comment: What do you mean by complex and slow? The code seems straightforward, and there is nothing obviously slow in the way you are doing the queries.

Comment: @sarra We don't need a description about what LINQ is and what's its purpose. Instead, we need some information about the questions which I asked in my previous comments.

Comment: My question is exactly is it possible to have one query using left joins that can have the same resut ? for example if I selected an account number, it returns only the rows with that account. And if I didn'tn it returns all my the rows.