# How do I concatenate a string with a variable returned from a database to produce a URL

Tags: sql-server, razor

I am trying to dynamically build a URL variable combining a server name parameter stored database side with the rest or the URL.

```
var ReportingServerParameter = db.Query("SELECT Value FROM Parameters WHERE Parameter = 'Server'");

@ObjectInfo.Print(ReportingServerParameter)

var ReportURL = String.Concat(("http://"),ReportingServerParameter);

@ObjectInfo.Print(ReportURL)
```

My string returns this:"http://System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection1[System.Object]"

I expect the output to be `http://SERVER1`

Comment: From the looks at it, I think you need to check on what db.query returns. Looks like a collection of objects. You will want to get the first member of the collection and extract its value as a string.

Comment: is this your c# code or sql query. ReportingServerParameter query where you execute via Entity. Also check what is the output of your sqlquery in the database side

Comment: you can check this link too- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235858/combining-the-results-of-two-linq-queries-into-a-single-var

Comment: The query will only return one row. How would I go about extracting it's value as a string?  I think that is the issue, ReportingServerParameter seems to be a collection rather the Value column from the first and only record returned. The code is embedded in a form in a cshtml page.

Comment: var ReportingServerParameter = db.Query("SELECT Value FROM Parameters WHERE Parameter = 'Server'");
 foreach(var row in ReportingServerParameter){
    var ParameterValue = row.Value; 
    @ObjectInfo.Print(ParameterValue)
    var ReportURL = String.Concat(("http://"),ParameterValue);
    @ObjectInfo.Print(ReportURL) 
}

Comment: The concatenation above works. I don't particularly like using foreach when there is just one row being returned. ReportURL contains the concatenated values but now I can't seem to reference ReportURL outside of the context of the foreach loop.