# Unable to combine two IQueryAbles

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two queries which are returning the same type of object. I want to combine them before executing (converting to list). However I am getting an error;

What I am trying

```
var current = context.Type.Include(b => b.Activity);
var pending = context.Type.IgnoreQueryFilter().Include(b => b.Activity).Where(b => !b.accepted);
return current.Concat(pending);
```

I am getting the following error

> ArgumentException: The input sequence must have items of type
>   'Test.Models.Type', but it has items of type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AnonymousObject'.

Comment: And how about `current.Concat(pending.ToList());` ?

Comment: I need the query further for pagination so cannot convert them to list just yet.

Comment: The error indicates that  `Test.Models.Type` != `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AnonymousObject` as both your objects (*I.e. `current` and `pending`*) are of different types. So, to solve the problem, you have to make both the objects of the same type. Either create a hardcoded type for both and then add a `.Select(s=> new ObjectType{})` or create an anonymous select which has same properties for both object.

Comment: It seems there is some issues with one of your queries thats why you arent able to merge them using Concat or Union.

Comment: Sounds like EF Core bug/limitation. What is the exact EF Core version?

Comment: @vikscool but why would the two be different when I am requesting the same type from the data context?

Comment: @ShahidManzoorBhat running two seperately gives me an Ienumberable of the exact same type.

Comment: @IvanStoev 2.1.

Comment: All I can do is to confirm that it's failing with the same exception even in latest 2.2.6, and is sort of working (no exceptions) in 3.1, but since `IgnoreQueryFilters()` is for the whole query, you get all entities duplicated in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you *start* a new query (starting from `context.table` again) you write a completely new query which has to be executed separately and can only be combined on the client side.

In your case you should check what `Where()` your context globally adds within `OnModelCreating()` (hence you use `IgnoreQueryFilter()`) and taking the logic from there and OR this into your second `Where()` clause.

Here is an example:

```
// Your setting of a global file e.g. hides all as deleted marked items
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Type>().HasQueryFilter(b => !b.IsDeleted);
}

// Instead of creating two queries, you have to manually combine both cases into one query
private void DoSomething()
{
    var combined = context.Type.IgnoreQueryFilter().Include(b => b.Activity).Where(b => !b.accepted || !b.IsDeleted);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the workaround. Can you explain a bit though why it would throw uncompatible type error though when combining even though both queries are the same? I can understand combining them not being a possibility but that particular error really confused me.

Comment: I know in my example both queries aren't the same but same error appears even when they are so I get that queries cannot be combined.

Comment: Then write a [minimal, reproducible sample program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), post it here and we can run it on our own to check what the issue is. But currently it's just wild guessing and if none of these satisfies you, we need a sample program, we can run on our own to debug and examine it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you update this line of code:

```
var pending = context.Type.IgnoreQueryFilter().Include(b => b.Activity).Where(b => !b.accepted);
```

To :

```
var pending = context.Type.IgnoreQueryFilter().Include(b => b.Activity).Where(b => !b.accepted).ToList();
```

Comment: No, I cannot execute it just yet. I need the combined queryable as source for pagination.

Comment: You are trying to perform Concat which basically returns the items from the first sequence followed by the items from the second sequence provided both have the same type. From the exception it seems the sequence you are trying to concat isnt of the same type. So you can check your second query.

Comment: Hey, so just for test purpose I made the second query and same as first and tried concat. I got the same error. So it seems like the linq operations are not working on queries.

Comment: Can you look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235858/combining-the-results-of-two-linq-queries-into-a-single-var